# mapping of orthogonal projection onto a plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I ran into the following statement: mapping of orthogonal projection onto a plane $x+y-7z = 0$ -- linear operator, but the mapping of orthogonal projection onto a plane $x+y-7z = 1$ -- non-linear map. Operator from $\mathbb{R}^3$. But why? I always think, that all projections $P^2 = P$ -- linear operators, no? I'm not sure, but maybe because this plane will not be a subspace?

And how can I check that some map is linear operator and some no? Only by checking the properties of linear map, like $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linear operator need to be at least maps the zero vector to zero vector. Since on the second plane zero vector is not on the plane then it will projected to some non zero vector. Hence the projection to the second plane is not linear.

Comment: So I can say, that this plane is not a subspace?

Comment: Yes, the second plane ia not a subspace. But you shouldn't give that as your reason for why the projection on the second plane is not linear.

Comment: You need to prove it first if there is indeed the connection betwern the two.

Comment: Yes, I just have to show that a linear mapping implies the existence of a homomorphism between groups of vector spaces and after proof that it always send identity element to the identity. 


So I can use this argument for proof that any "space shift" non-linear operator too?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.